# Java Android Como montar um banco de dados randômico?

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite

Na aplicação para Android, usando Java, recebo uma string em Json parecida com essa:

`String teste = "{\n" + "  \"nometabela\":{\n" + "    \"id\":\"f83d6101cc\",\n" + "    \"coluna1\":\"codigo\",\n" + "    \"coluna2\":\"descricao\",\"coluna3\":\"quantidade\"\n" + "  }`

Com esses dados, preciso criar o banco usando SQLite. Por exemplo, o dado "nometabela"dentro da string Json vai ter que ser o nome da tabela, o "id" será "f83d6101cc", a o nome da primeiro coluna será "codigo", a segunda "descricao" e a terceira "quantidade".

Com os dados fixos, consegui criar o banco.

Porém, os dados não serão sempre assim. Eu nunca vou saber como será esse arquivo Json. O banco criado terá que ser baseado nele, então poderão haver mais colunas, ou menos colunas, etc.

Como faço pra ler essa String Json e criar um banco de acordo com os valores passados por ela? Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer seu código reconhecer que cada " : " passado pelo Json significa uma nova coluna. E o que estiver a esquerda desses pontos significa o nome da tabela, e a direita seu conteudo.